# Failed to download repository information 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, update-manager, repository

While trying to update my computer i get the following error

```
W:Failed to fetch http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/<precise>/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when updating packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Comment: That could not help in my case.

Comment: @Parto: This is a 403 Forbidden error. @heisenberg: In your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, make sure you don't have angle brackets around `precise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means in your `sources.list` is an URL entry that cannot be accessed ([403 Forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)).

You can remove the line from your `sources.list`:

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with an editor and look for the lines that look like this:

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/<precise>/main/binary-i386
```

Now comment them out. Add a `#` before each of those lines that they look like this and save the file:

```
#deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/<precise>/main/binary-i386
```

Maybe there are other files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You have to check all files in that directory too.

When finished, type `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal and your update process should work again.